# java parse double value from string as literal value

Tags: java

How do I parse strings as literal double values?  I have a set of probability values I am parsing using `Double.valueOf(probabilityString)` that need to sum exactly to `1.0d`.

For example, the resulting sum of the double values is `0.999999...` when the probability strings are `0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1`.

What I would like to have is for the double values to be parsed in as `0.2d, 0.5d, 0.2d, 0.1d`, is this possible?

I am dealing with a third-party library that accepts `double[]` as argument and throws an exception if the double values do not sum up precisely to `1.0d`.

Comment: You need something higher precision than floating point numbers then.  That's just the way floating point numbers work.  Certain numbers cannot be represented exactly, so summing those numbers will not give the result you expect.

Comment: You need to assume that 0.9999999999999999 is so close to 1.0 it doesn't matter.

Comment: Odd third party library that makes this assumption.

Answer (score 4):

doubles are only 64 bit long. There are an infinity of real numbers. It's thus impossible to represent exactly each real into a 64-bit double. So using doubles will always lead to approximated results. If you need absolute precision, use BigDecimal.

Comment: +1 There is an infinity of whole numbers and *for each* whole number there is an infinity of real numbers. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) that is available in Java.

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891318/bigdecimal-error), It will surely help you.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
DecimalFormat df =(DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getInstance(); 
df.setParseBigDecimal(true); 
BigDecimal bd = (BigDecimal) df.parse(probabilityString);
```